# Can you get your fingerprints removed from the FBI database?

Tags: fbi, fingerprint

Can you get your fingerprints removed from the FBI database after a background check? The FBI website says, "NGI will remove the retained civil fingerprints should the submitting agency request removal, or removal is required by court order." Is there a way to do this as a regular Joe who had a simple background check done?

Answer (score 3):

**Is there a way to do this as a regular Joe who had a simple background check done?**

Apparently not...

> It is important to note that this retention and searching of civil
> fingerprints is authorized only for those individuals whose
> employment, license, or other benefit requires that the individual not
> commit a prohibited criminal action. Moreover, these individuals are
> provided with a Privacy Act statement and other actual notices
> regarding the retention and searching of their fingerprints.
>
> [...]
>
> ...NGI retains the civil fingerprints after completion of the
> noncriminal justice background check. The fingerprints are retained
> regardless of whether there is any match to criminal history
> information. When the civil fingerprints are submitted for retention
> in NGI, the fingerprints are searched against the existing civil,
> criminal, and unsolved latent files. Latent fingerprints are
> fingerprints collected from locations or property associated with
> criminal or national security investigations. Likewise, once civil
> fingerprints are retained in NGI, all incoming civil and criminal
> fingerprints will cascade against those fingerprints, and latent
> fingerprint contributors may choose to have their latent fingerprints
> cascade as well. NGI will remove the retained civil fingerprints
> should the submitting agency request removal, or removal is required
> by court order.
>
> This retention and searching of the civil fingerprints provides, in
> effect, **an “ongoing” background check** that permits employers,
> licensors, and other authorized entities to learn of criminal conduct
> by a trusted individual, unless the contributor does not subscribe to
> a rap back service. It eliminates the need for periodic rescreening of
> the individual and the resubmission of fingerprints.

https://www.fbi.gov/services/information-management/foipa/privacy-impact-assessments/next-generation-identification-ngi-retention-and-searching-of-noncriminal-justice-fingerprint-submissions

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it doesn't specifically say that fingerprints *can't* be removed. When my employment with them is done (this wouldn't be a permanent job), I'd hate thinking that my fingerprints are in a database somewhere waiting to get some partial match for the rest of my life.